# One of the IF loops isn't working properly and I don't know why

Tags: autohotkey

I am working a lot with SEO so I made myself a shortcut for quickly checking on websites, issue is for some reason the second IF statement inside the function is not working properly ( if I type in "seo" it asks me for the domain I want to check and runs properly, but if I type in "whois" the Inputbox does not pop and it jumps straight to the whois.domaintools.com website ( without the URL extension )

here is the code I made so far

```
collectAction(){
InputBox, userAction, ,Which action would you like to perform?, , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
if(userAction="seo")
    InputBox, seoUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
    Run, https://freetools.seobility.net/en/seocheck/check?url=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.%seoUrl%`%2F&crawltype=1
    return
if(userAction="whois")
    InputBox, whoisUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
    Run, https://whois.domaintools.com/%whoisUrl%
    return          
}
```

thanks in advance!
p.s if this info has any impact on the process i am calling this function with a hotkey (F1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the commands in the if clause between {} block

```
    collectAction(){
    InputBox, userAction, ,Which action would you like to perform?, , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
    if(userAction="seo") {
        InputBox, seoUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
        Run, https://freetools.seobility.net/en/seocheck/check?url=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.%seoUrl%`%2F&crawltype=1
        return
    } ; end if 
    if(userAction="whois") {
        InputBox, whoisUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, Arial,
        Run, https://whois.domaintools.com/%whoisUrl%
        return          
    } ; end of if
    } ; end of function
```

Answer (score 0):

changing two consecutive if statemets to if - else works

```
collectAction(){

InputBox, userAction, ,Which action would you like to perform?, , 300, 130, ,, ,
if(userAction="seo") {
    InputBox, seoUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, ,
    Run, https://freetools.seobility.net/en/seocheck/check?url=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.%seoUrl%`%2F&crawltype=1
    return
}
else if(userAction="whois") {
    InputBox, whoisUrl, ,Please enter the domain you want to check., , 300, 120, ,, ,
    Run, https://whois.domaintools.com/%whoisUrl%
    return          
    }
}
```

function call example:

```
F1::
collectAction()
return
```

Comment: that isn't what solved the problem though, it's the braces you added. the `else if` is logically equivalent to the original code because of the `return` in the block.